# The "video tag" is not working on React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tags

i wanna use "video tag" for background but it doesn work.
what is wrong..?

```
const Auth = () => {
const covervid = '../css/video/vidbackground.mp4';
  return (
    <div className="Auth">
      <video autoPlay={true} muted={true} loop={true} style={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <source src={covervid} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

Comment: should be `autoplay` not `autoPlay`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.